# How to convert audio files to 'RIFF' or 'RIFX' format for tensorflow audio-classifier?

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio, nlp, google-colaboratory

I was following this [tensorflow audio-classifier tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/models/modify/model_maker/audio_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=ayd7UqCfQQFU).

I replaced the bird-sound-dataset with a small audio-dataset I recorded on my Mac, and once I got to this code part: `random_audio = get_random_audio_file() show_bird_data(random_audio)` , I got this error:

[[image]

I looked for solutions to this problem on multiple sites (even stack overflow) but couldn't find any answers.

Should I (somehow?) convert all my .wav audio files to the RFF and RIFX format, or is there a way to change the actual code to accept my audio files?

Also, here is [my google-colab-notebook link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1not_oAB8gwDgz1LedYrCDV1Tl9DfmVmN?usp=sharing) in case more of the code needs to be viewed.

Comment: Same question here? No answer after 3 months?

Answer (score 1):

Basically **scipy.io** doesn't support the wav file you are opening, I found a simple solution to this, by converting the file to wav using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis). Try this even if your original file is a wav file, as it may be encoded in a different manner. Execute this command in the Colab:

```
!ffmpeg -i input.avi output.wav
```

This will store your file in the output.wav in a format readable by scipy.wav. You could run this for each file beforehand or in a separate function using subprocess from os library of Python. That will be something like:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["powershell", "ffmpeg -i input.avi output.wav"], shell=True)
```

Note that you might need to save that file you get from the get_random_audio_file() function as a separate file before running the above commands, this is if the function returns the audio file directly, you may do this as follows:

```
with open("audio_file.wav", "wb") as audio:
    random_audio.save(audio)
```

Keep in mind, you would still need to run the same code for the conversion as before.